# While loop iterations issue in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, while-loop

I have a code

```
public void LoadProducts()
     {
         //StringBuilder sbProducts = new StringBuilder();
         string qry = "Select * from tbl_Products order by ProductId";
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
         con.Open();
         sbProducts="<table cellpadding='0' align='center' height: '250px'; width: '1000px'><tr>";

         using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
         {
             while (sdr.Read())
             {
                 sbProducts = sbProducts + "<form action='ProductDetail.aspx'><td style='border-right:1px solid
 blue;border-top:1px solid blue;border-bottom:1px solid
 blue;border-left:1px solid blue;text-align:center;width:300px'>";
                 Session["code"] = sdr[0].ToString();
                 sbProducts = sbProducts + "<img src= " + sdr[5].ToString().Substring(2) + " width=120px height=150px><br>";
                 sbProducts = sbProducts + sdr[0].ToString() + sdr[2].ToString() + "<br>";
                 sbProducts = sbProducts + sdr[3].ToString() + "<br>";
                 sbProducts = sbProducts + "Rs: " + sdr[4].ToString();
                 sbProducts = sbProducts + "<br><input type='hidden' name='pid'  value='" + Session["code"] + "'><input type='submit'
 value='View Details'>";
                 sbProducts = sbProducts + "</td></form>";
             }
             sbProducts = sbProducts + "</table>";
             CellTwo = sbProducts.ToString();
             con.Close();
         }
     }
```

it contains a form that need to be repeated with every iteration but on first iteration, while loop is missing this form (html) element the rest of the iteration it works OK.
i dont know what the issue is any why while loop is missing form element in first iteration.

Comment: Your structure is not well formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Share us your html output please
By the look of things you'll generate something like this :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <form>
      <td></td>
    </form>
</table>
```

You're not closing the tr and the form should be in a td , not between tr and td.
The result should look like this :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form></form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: 'share us your html output please' should be a comment on the OP's question, not a lead-in to the answer.  But your answer is a valid place to start.

Comment: Wanted to make sure i interpreted his code correctly but i do feel that this is the solution to his problem. Browsers tend to do strange things with badly structured tables

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
public void LoadProducts()
     {
         //StringBuilder sbProducts = new StringBuilder();
         string qry = "Select * from tbl_Products order by ProductId";
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
         con.Open();
         sbProducts="<table cellpadding='0' align='center' height: '250px'; width: '1000px'><tr>";
         int counter=0;
         using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
         {
             while (sdr.Read())
             {
                 if(counter++=0)
                 {
                 sbProducts = sbProducts + "<form action='ProductDetail.aspx'><td style='border-right:1px solid
 blue;border-top:1px solid blue;border-bottom:1px solid
 blue;border-left:1px solid blue;text-align:center;width:300px'>";
                 }
                 sbProducts = sbProducts +"<tr>";
                 Session["code"] = sdr[0].ToString();
                 sbProducts = sbProducts + "<img src= " + sdr[5].ToString().Substring(2) + " width=120px height=150px><br>";
                 sbProducts = sbProducts + sdr[0].ToString() + sdr[2].ToString() + "<br>";
                 sbProducts = sbProducts + sdr[3].ToString() + "<br>";
                 sbProducts = sbProducts + "Rs: " + sdr[4].ToString();
                 sbProducts = sbProducts + "<br><input type='hidden' name='pid'  value='" + Session["code"] + "'><input type='submit'
 value='View Details'>";
                 sbProducts = sbProducts + "</td>";
                 sbProducts = sbProducts +"</tr>";
             }
             //sbProducts = sbProducts + "</table>";
            // CellTwo = sbProducts.ToString();
             con.Close();
         }
         sbProducts = sbProducts + "</table>";
         CellTwo = sbProducts.ToString();
     }
```

similarly you can add `</form>` and table outside the while loop.